# Test Service with Mockito, when Id is set by database

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

I have a function createObject() in my service rest Service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    //Repos and contructor

   @Transactional
   public ObjectDto createObject(Object) {

       Mother mother = new Mother(name, age);
       Kid kid = new Kid(name, age);

       mother.addKid(kid);

       this.motherRepo.saveAndFlush(mother); 

       Long kidId = kid.getId();

       doStuffWithKidId();

       return new ObjectDto()
            .withMother(mother)
            .withKid(kid)
            .build();
  }
}
```

My entity for mother/kid is basically like this:

```
@Entity
@Table("mother")
public class mother() {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="id)
   private Long id;

   //other attributes, including @OneToMany for Kid
   //Getter/Setter

}
```

There is a similar Entity for Kid.

As you can see, the id is set by the database. There is no setter for id in the entity. The constructor is without id as well.

Now I want to test my service. I mock my repos and want to verify, that my ObjectDto contains the values, like id.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MotherRepo motherRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void createObjectTest() {

        ObjectDto expectedObjectDto = setup...;
        Object inputObject = setup...;

        assertThat.(this.myService.createObject(inputObject))
             .isEqualToComparingFieldByField(expectedObjectDto);

    }
}
```

The expected ObjectDto looks something like

```
{
   "motherId":1,
   "motherAge":40,
   "kidId":1
   ...
}
```

The problem is, that the id is set up by the database. Since there is no database and the repository is mock with Mockito, this value is always null. Even if I set my expectedObjectDto with null as id, I need the id in the "doStuffWithKidId()" in the service. Atm I get a NullPointerException.

Is there a possibility to set the id, like with ReflectionTestUtils.setField()? In literature I read, that a service should always be tested using mocks. Is this correct or do I need a in-memory db like H2?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `doAnswer`...

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Java6Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoSettingDatabaseIds {

    private static class TestEntity {
        private long id;
        private String text;

        public TestEntity(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
    }

    private interface TestEntityDAO {
        void save(TestEntity entity);
    }

    private static long someLogicToTest(TestEntityDAO dao, TestEntity entity) {
        dao.save(entity);
        return entity.getId();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDatabaseGeneratedId() {
        long expectedId = 12345L;

        TestEntityDAO dao = mock(TestEntityDAO.class);
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity("[MESSAGE]");

        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField((TestEntity) invocation.getArgument(0), "id", expectedId);
            return null;
        }).when(dao).save(entity);

        assertThat(someLogicToTest(dao, entity)).isEqualTo(expectedId);
    }
}
```

To answer your comment, just do the same thing to the `Kid` collection, for example...

```
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Mother toSave = (Mother) invocation.getArgument(0);
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(toSave, "id", expectedId);

            for (int k = 0; k < toSave.getKids().size(); k++) {
                ReflectionTestUtils.setField(toSave.getKids().get(k), "id", expectedId + k + 1);
            }

            return null;
        }).when(dao).save(entity);
```

This will set the `id` of the `Mother` to `expectedId` and the IDs of the `Kid`s to `expectedId + 1`, `expectedId + 2` etc.

Comment: It works, thank. I just hat to adjust it to doAnswer(...).when(doa).save(**any()**), because I can't give it into the someLogicToTest().

Comment: It works for the mother entity. But I am not able to use the solution for the kid entity, since I don't have a doa.save() or something like that, that uses it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks mate, it works! If I could I would upvote mulitple times :) Thank you very very much, I was struggling with this for 2 days now.